# How can I strip all but hex from file or input?

Tags: c, hex, scanf, fgets

I'm trying to read a file with a mix of random sentences, data, and blocks of hex.  I'd like to only read in the hex blocks.  A short example of the file is below.

---

**Small sample file**

```
Serial Number   :   1234
More Data       :   7-9-2

-------------------------

Mak:  A5 12 00 24 00 01 22 00 4F 11
      A2 48 4A D1 53 6D 8A D1 61 40

t+00:00:00:00   : Mix one

Mak:  A5 22 30 44 50 01 22 00 4F 11
      A2 18 2A 31 43 6D 8A D1 61 40 

A random sentence.
```

---

Below is what I've been using to read all the lines in the file, and frequently adding `strstr()` methods to match a specific hex value I was looking for.  The entire process of matching hex would be much easier if I could strip out everything that wasn't in the format of the hex blocks, or only read into the stream only the hex.

```
void ReturnAllLines(char *filePath)
{
    char currentLine[100];
    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");

    while(fgets(currentLine, sizeof(currentLine), file) != NULL)
    {
        printf(currentLine);
    }
}
```

In other languages I've done similar things using regex, or built in methods, but I'm new to c, and I'm not sure what the best method for this would be.

The final output would ideally be similar to the following:

`A5 12 00 24 00 01 22 00 4F 11 A2 48 4A D1 53 6D 8A D1 61 40`

`A5 22 30 44 50 01 22 00 4F 11 A2 18 2A 31 43 6D 8A D1 61 40`

With each block having something to differentiate between the two.  But even a single massive line of hex would work much better.  I've looked into using `sscanf()`, but everything I've tried has failed, and I quit attempting because I wasn't sure it was capable of doing this.

Comment: Would you really want to include `S5` - or is that a typo?

Comment: What does `S5` mean for that input

Comment: Do all hex blocks start with 'Mak'?

Comment: All hex blocks begin with either ```Mak: ``` or one of 2 or 3 other start words.  The S5 was a mistake on my part.  I hand typed all of that in as an example.  My bad.

Comment: May be identify the lines with start words and then use strtok() to get hex values?

Comment: Edited out the ```S5``` so it doesn't trigger future hex readers.  I'm trying to catch up :)

Comment: Okay may want to fix the typo in the "...final output..." part as well.

Comment: C does not contain any useful helpers such as regex. Does it have to be C or could it be C++(11+) which does have regex? strncmp() can be used to detect keywords at the start of lines read with fgets(). You can also use strtol() to read the hex numbers, if you wish.

Comment: It has to be C.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: By the way the function suggestions are C functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gets you pretty close I think. It uses `strtok()` to split each line in to space-delimited tokens - then uses `scanf()` to check if the token is a hexadecimal character.

You can slot it in to your `ReturnAllLines()` function (by replacing `printf(currentLine)` with `PrintLineHex(currentLine)`).

```
void PrintLineHex(char *line) {
    char *nl = NULL, *tok = NULL;
    int convs = 0;
    unsigned ch = '\0';
    int hex_line = 0;

    nl = strchr(line, '\n');
    if (nl) *nl = '\0';  // Remove new-line char ...
    tok = strtok(line, " ");
    hex_line = 0;
    while (tok) {
        convs = sscanf(tok, "%x", &ch);
        if (convs == 1 && strlen(tok) == 2) {
            hex_line = 1;
            printf("%02hhX ", ch);
        }
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if (hex_line) puts("");
}
```

It also checks the width of each token. You can tweak that aspect fairly easily if you want to accommodate hexadecimal values of varying character widths.

Output using your sample input ...

```
A5 12 00 24 00 01 22 00 4F 11   
A2 48 4A D1 53 6D 8A D1 61 40   
A5 22 30 44 50 01 22 00 4F 11   
A2 18 2A 31 43 6D 8A D1 61 40
```

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot in there that I didn't know about.  It fits what I needed perfectly.

Comment: @trueCamelType: I'm glad it helped, and appreciate the feedback.